# How to install mysqlnd php 5.3 for cpanel with Easy Apache

Tags: mysql, php5

I would need to install the mysqlnd driver for php, however am using a cPanel server and have to use easy apache.

I have set up raw-opts for

```
--with-mysql=mysqlnd 
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd 
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

however I am getting the error:

```
mysql_config not found
```

Has anyone had any success getting mysqlnd installed on cpanel, for php 5.3?

Comment: Start [here](http://cpanel.net/support/).

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the response, I have read through all the posts i've been able to find on mysqlnd, both through support and cpanels community forums; the raw-opts were the only documented thing I have been able to find.  Other posts appear to say it is possible but not supported, however the most recent post was a year ago, asking basically the same question, but getting no response.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the [`mysql_config` program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-config.html), which should have come with your MySQL installation.

If that program is not available you will have to check/reinstall the MySQL packages, or rebuild MySQL from source and ensure that the `mysql_config` program is installed somewhere where the PHP installer can find it.